# Using jQuery to give Grails constraint errors a nice appearance (but not client side validation)

Tags: jquery, grails

On the server, Grails provides constraint validation of the fields that will be saved into domain object / database, and then provides the `<g:renderErrors>` tag to display any field errors in the html/form page, generally displayed at the top of the page.

What would be the easiest way to take these server side errors and instead display them next to each field in a red error callout?  I.e. what's a simple (jQuery) library to just put an error callout next to a given field, without doing validation in the client?

(Grails 1.3.7, plan to update to 2.0 later) - edited

Comment: What version of Grails are you using? Generating the view I think the input receive an error class (border: red)

Comment: Grails 1.3.7, and will update to Grails 2.0 after it stabilizes

Answer (score 3):

The hasErrors(bean: bean, field: field, ) tag in the groovy taglib will help you here. As Sergio said, you can call it on your GSP and use it to add css styles to your inputs (or input containers). Here's an example for a view which has a "person" model passed, which has a field called "name" and I want to apply a 'errors' css class:

```
<td class="${hasErrors(bean: person, field: 'name', 'errors')} text">
```

As for intelligent, user-friendly messages about "why" a field is invalid, you can add a i18n property code to your Domain validator, corresponding text in your i18n folder, and I believe use something to the effect of renderError to print that message (it should be attached to the error). Then you could lookup the error by the field name, and inject that message into the view. Not 100% sure on how to do that though.

Comment: Thanks Will.  Yah, it is renderError.  I'm currently looking at using this tag to set the content of an error tooltip for the given field, using the qtip tool tip library to make the error call-out.